# Using the LibVLCSharp Library is there a way to set the chapters or tracks of the Media item programmatically?

Tags: libvlc, libvlcsharp

In the program I am working on, I am looking for a way to create chapter cues in the mp4 file programmatically without altering the mp4 file. I am currently replacing our Windows.UI `MediaPlayerElement` with the `LibVLCSharp` library, but I am running into difficulty in this functionality. I am looking for some type of functionality similar to the [TimedMetaDataTrack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.timedmetadatatrack?view=winrt-22621) in windows, which is what we have used previously

Currently I have the media being set like so

```
    public async Task<bool> SetMedia(string path, bool loop = false)
    {
           if (_libVLC == null || _mediaPlayer == null)
                return false;            
            CloseMedia();
            Uri videoPath = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/" + path);
            StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(videoPath);
            _fileStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            _mediaStream = new StreamMediaInput(_fileStream);
            var _playerMedia = new Media(_libVLC, _mediaStream);
            if (loop)
                _playerMedia.AddOption($":input-repeat={int.MaxValue}");
            _mediaPlayer.Media = _playerMedia;
            await _playerMedia.Parse(MediaParseOptions.ParseLocal);
            _mediaPlayer.Play();
            _playerMedia.Dispose();
            _playerMedia = null;
            return true;
       }
```

It works well and there is no issues with the media playing, however I have not been able to find documentation for this specific need.

I have attempted to access the `MediaTracks[]` array of the media, but I think this may be readonly and not possible to change in order to update the metadata. Is there a different way I can do this? Essentially, I need the tracks to be configurable and not based off of the existing metadata of the mp4 file. I am sure there must be something I can pass to the `AddOption`  on creating the media, but I haven't been able to find anything in the [command line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) about creating tracks rather than how it should access existing ones.